# How does map function convert a numerical value in international numbering format in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, map-function

I am working in python. I have a dataframe object `Top15`, which has a column named `population`. Now, I have to convert the numerical value in this column according to the international numbering system, eg `12345` will be converted to `12,345`.

I found a code somewhere and I wrote my code accordingly, but I do not understand how it works. It would be really great if someone could help me understand how it's working.

The code is:

```
Top15['population'] = Top15['population'].map('{:,}'.format)
print(Top15['population'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`'{:,}'.format()` is a string format. The `:,` means your numbers will be represented as strings and a `,` will be added after every 3 numbers. Some examples:

```
'{:,}'.format(123)
>>> '123'

'{:,}'.format(1234)
>>> '1,234'

'{:,}'.format(123456)
>>> '123,456'

'{:,}'.format(1234567)
>>> '1,234,567'
```

You can read more about [string.format() here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Answer (score 0):

this a example map() use.

```
map(function_to_apply, list_of_inputs) 
x = map(lambda n: return len(n), object)


Top15['population'] = map(lambda n:'{:,}'.format(n),Top15['population'])
print(Top15['population'])
```